# Creating a BulletCollisionShape from an .egg file

Tags: python, bulletphysics, panda3d

I'm writing a game using Panda3D 1.10 using the [Bullet Open Source Physics Library 1.5.8](http://www.bulletphysics.org/mediawiki-1.5.8/index.php/Main_Page). How do I generate a collision shape from an egg file?

This is the code I have so far:

```
    tree = BulletRigidBodyNode('Tree')
    tree.setMass(10.0)
    shape = getCollisionFromEgg('tree.egg') # This is the 'magic function' I'm after
    tree.addShape(shape)
    np = render.attachNewNode(tree)
    np.setPos(10, 0, 2)
    self.world.attachRigidBody(tree)
    model = loader.loadModel('tree.egg')
    model.reparentTo(np)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that I've got a soulution, however, I also have problems.

```python
def toShape(model):
    shape=BulletTriangleMesh()

    geomNodeCollection = model.findAllMatches('**/+GeomNode')
    for nodePath in geomNodeCollection:
        geomNode = nodePath.node()
        for i in range(geomNode.getNumGeoms()):
            geom = geomNode.getGeom(i)
            state = geomNode.getGeomState(i)
            shape.addGeom(geom)
    shape=BulletTriangleMeshShape(shape, True)
    return shape
```

It looks like working, but I've got problems... Give it a try.